# How to share an html page

Tags: html, sharing

I was working on a simple text adventure game and I just finished the beta version on the website I was using, so I was super psyched but the website didn't have an easy publish link instead I could download an html that was saved on my computer. I was kinda disappointed but I figured well I can just share the html file in any file sharing service but anything I tried would end up as just codes and not actually open the html, I mean I want to avoid the users actually having to download the game because I'm gonna keep updating it and their saves will just be lost, and google drive and dropbox have stopped html static whatever its called hosting, I'm searching google for another solution in the meantime, if you guys know please help

Comment: This site is for programming questions. How/Where to host your site is off-topic.

Comment: ooh ok so do you know which community should I ask then

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/ would probably work pretty well for what you want.

Comment: I found another way, took me some time though, the login button was green and the background was a darker green stupid design but whatever atleast I can finally publish it

Answer (score 0):

**A lot of website makers out there will let you implement your own code in if you so choose** (typically people don't do that thought because the point of a website builder is so you don't have to code). I can only name one website off the top of my head, **[websitebuilder.com](https://my.websitebuilder.com/)** but I'm sure there are many others that will let you do it too. The only problem with this is that **if you don't want to pay for the website hosting then your url will have .websitebuilder after it** and before the .com (not just done by websitebuilder.com, but every free hosting site.) as vbdvelp said, this question isn't exactly on topic relative to programming but I can definitely see why you think it might be. Good luck and I hoped this helped!